# Read JMS properties from an InOnly message in Camel

Tags: jms, apache-camel

When sending (InOnly) JMS messages with Apache Camel, can I read back the different JMS headers that might have been set automatically on the message, when it was sent?

```
from("foo:bar")
 .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly,"jms:queue:whatever")
 .log("msg id set = ${in.header.JMSMessageId}");
```

I just can't figure out how to send the message "one way" but keeping the sent JMS message as "in" message in the route afterwards.

Background:
I know that I can present some values, but it would be easier if they where set by the actual JMS implementation. For instance, in this case, I want to work with WebSphere SIBus, WebSphere MQ and ActiveMQ. It's best to rely on WebSphere MQs internal message id format, because it will only index certain message formats. It might be similar aspects on the WebSphere SIBus implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available [starting at 2.10.3 and 2.11.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5763).

Comment: not sure if it's possible to maintain the original JMSDestination ...I might need some help to clarify this